How can i break the code after the first if and print so it will only display the message and not continue
I'm new to python and i cant find a solution.
images = [rock, paper, scissors]

person = int(input("What do you chose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n"))

if person >=3 or person < 0:
  print("You typed an invalid number,please choose 0,1 or 2")

Want to stop to code here if the "if" statement is not fulffilled so the code cant go further to print the image downwards.
else:
  print(images[person])

computer = random.randint(0, 2)
print("Computer chose:")
print(images[computer])

I tried putting in a loop so i can use break but i didnt manage to make it work.

You can either use exit(1), or just indent the rest of the code to the else level so it does not get executed in the first case

...or put your code into a function and use return.

worked like a charm with exit(1). thank you

There are multiple ways to "break" your code. The best solution depends on the rest of the code ..

Using exit() to quit the application with an error code. An error code of 0 means "everything went fine" and a non 0 error code means "something wrong happened".

images = [rock, paper, scissors]

person = int(input("What do you chose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n"))

if person >=3 or person < 0:
  print("You typed an invalid number,please choose 0,1 or 2")
  exit(1)

print(images[person])

computer = random.randint(0, 2)
print("Computer chose:")
print(images[computer])


You can indent the portion of code accordingly to the execution flow.

images = [rock, paper, scissors]

person = int(input("What do you chose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n"))

if person >=3 or person < 0:
  print("You typed an invalid number,please choose 0,1 or 2")
else:
  print(images[person])

  computer = random.randint(0, 2)
  print("Computer chose:")
  print(images[computer])


As suggested in a comment, you can also create a dedicated function and use the return.

def myfunction():
  images = [rock, paper, scissors]

  person = int(input("What do you chose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n"))

  if person >=3 or person < 0:
    print("You typed an invalid number,please choose 0,1 or 2")
    return 1

  print(images[person])

  computer = random.randint(0, 2)
  print("Computer chose:")
  print(images[computer])

  return 0

myfunction()

From my point of view, the use of suggestion #1 best fits your needs because you provide your user an error code which tells about the faced error.
